# Expectation value summation

Tags: summation

I’m running into problems with a summation

$$\langle p \rangle = \frac{\sum_{p=0}^{N-1}px^p}{\sum_{p=0}^{N-1}x^p} = x\frac{d}{dx}ln(\sum_{p=0}^{N-1}x^p)$$

I know I’ve seen this before but I can’t remember the justification to get it summed to

$$\frac{Nx^N}{x^N-1}-\frac{x}{x-1}$$

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know the sum of a finite geometric series?

Comment: Thanks for the push!

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is pretty straightforward, posting for any future viewers... you need to start by breaking down the sum into $$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}x^p = \sum_{p=0}^{N-1}x^p + \sum_{p=N}^{\infty}x^p$$ then

$$ \sum_{p=0}^{N-1}x^p = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty}x^p -  \sum_{p=N}^{\infty}x^p$$ and we get $$x\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^N}{1-x}\right) = x\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(1-x^N)-\ln(1-x)]$$ from which the result follows.